# Rolagem entre telas

Tags: android

Quero fazer uma rolagem entre telas diferentes. Por exemplo, criar uma rolagem igual do menu de celular ou da área de trabalho que quando puxada uma vai ocupando o espaço da outra. Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crie uma pasta chamada "anim" no diretorio "res".
La dentro, crie os arquivos:

**slide_in_left_transition.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate
        android:duration="400"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

**slide_in_right_transition.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate
        android:duration="400"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

**slide_out_left_transition.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <translate
        android:duration="400"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

**slide_out_right_transition.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <translate
        android:duration="400"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

Agora quando voce quiser fazer a animação de ir pra frente, chame o metodo `overridePendingTransition()` após dar `startActivity`, por exemplo:

```java
Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
startActivity(i);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out_left_transition, R.anim.slide_in_right_transition);
```

Agora para fazer o efeito contrario, coloque `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left_transition, R.anim.slide_out_right_transition);` logo depois de fechar a activity, seja depois de um `finish();` ou no evento do botão voltar do celular (veja exemplo abaixo).

```java
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left_transition, R.anim.slide_out_right_transition);
}
```

Comment: Ótima implementação, não tinha a minima noção que era tão simples (ou não). Muito bom seu exemplo, implementei aqui e funcionou perfeita, só não é bem do jeito que pergunta queria, que acredito que seja trocar as views por Touch Left e Touch Right, mas com um pouco de empenho, acredito que seja possível a partir desse seu exemplo. +1 por ter me ajuda.

Comment: Realmente fiquei em dúvida se ele queria realmente isso, vamos ver quando ele responder hehe Valeu!!

Comment: Mas isso não tira o mérito de sua solução, muito boa, só é necessário adaptar para funcionar para a questão. Em minha implementação sobrescrevi o método `finish()` igual o `onBackPressed()`, se a `Activity` é finalizada através desse método e não pelo botão back;

Comment: Esqueci desse detalhe, também faço isso quando necessário. Vou editar na resposta! Valeu cara :p